# Python "unexpected indent"

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this python code but i keep getting error message "unexpected indent". I'm not sure whats wrong. the spacing seem to be fine. Any idea's?

```
services = ['Service1']  
 for service in services:  
      try:  
           print service + '\t',  
           if 'notavailable' not in requests.get('some website' + service + '&username=' + username, headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}).text:  
                print 'Available'  
           else:  
                print ''  
      except Exception as e:  
           print e
```

Comment: The spacing doesn't look fine to me; the second line has an extra space. Please include the *full error message*.

Comment: I don't know for sure if this applies for Python 3, but at least in Python 2, if you have hard tabs (an actual tab key) mixed with soft tabs (tabs filled with spaces), there will be indent errors.

Comment: @Zhouster: That's true if you aren't using 8-space hard tabs. Python assumes hard tabs indent on 8-space bounds.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Oh, that's pretty useful information. I'm almost always using 4-space tabs, but I'm assuming 8-space hard tab is the default for editing programs like Vim?

Comment: 8-space tabs are the default back to the VT100 terminals of old and probably before (typewriters?). People started using 4-space tabs because they didn't run everything off an 80-column screen with a few levels of indent, but that was never a standard (I've seen 2- and 3-space tabs as well) and hard tabs were used both to save disk space and because text editors back then did a lousy job of handling soft tabs (i.e. made out of spaces), often leading to ragged indentation. Unix has always assumed 8-space tabs, which is why Python uses it. The Linux kernel sources use 8-space tabs, too.

Comment: The main coding standard for Python specifies 4-space indents (soft tabs). You can use other indents but good python modes for editors should do 4-space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`services = ['Service1']`  is not in line with your for loop.

```
services = ['Service1']  
 for service in services: <-- unexpected indentation
```

Just line up your code as below.

```
services = ['Service1'] # need to line up with loop
for service in services: 
    try:
        print service + '\t',
        if 'notavailable' not in requests.get('some website' + service + '&username=' + username, headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}).text:
            print 'Available'
        else:
            print ''
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Your code is also `python 2` syntax not `python 3`

Comment: He's probably running it under a `Python 2` interpreter.

Comment: @ThomasHobohm, almost certainly  but it is tagged python3

Comment: I think he was just clicking recommended tags. But it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Thanks. Worked perfectly.